# Writing files with limited user-prompt inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I need a code that prompts the user for a name and a number, but the maximum is 3. Then it will write the code to an empty text file, even though the names are only 2 or 3.

```
name = True
while name:
    if name == "done entering":
        name = False
        break
    else:
        name = True
        firstName1 = input("Enter your first Name: ")
        lastName1 = input("Enter your last Name here: ")
        studentID1 = input("Enter your id number: ")
        firstName2 = input("Enter your first Name: ")
        lastName2 = input("Enter your last Name here: ")
        studentID2 = input("Enter your id number: ")
        firstName3 = input("Enter your first Name: ")
        lastName3 = input("Enter your last Name here: ")
        studentID3 = input("Enter your id number: ")
        break

inFile = open("studentInfo.txt", 'a')
inFile.write("Name: " + firstName1 + " " + lastName1)
inFile.write("\nStudentID: " + studentID1)
inFile.write("Name: " + firstName2 + " " + lastName2)
inFile.write("\nStudentID: " + studentID2)
inFile.write("Name: " + firstName3 + " " + lastName3)
inFile.write("\nStudentID: " + studentID3)
inFile.close()
print("\nDone! Data is saved in file: studentInfo.txt")
```

I copy-pasted my first code and it kind of works, but whenever I run it in the Python interpreter, there is a "y" before the "enter first names" and I can't enter 2 names only, it requires 3. And how can I make that shorter too... TY

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the "y" before the "enter first names" behavior. Perhaps a
copy and paste issue in your environment.

To enter less than 3 entries then you need something to limit to 3 and can
allow less than 3. This may need different data handling like using a list.

Create a list to store the 3 groups of entries. A list has length, so use
the length of the list as the while statement. The loop will end after 3 groups
of entries.

Break from the loop if the first name entry is empty as that implies no more
input. Continue the loop if other items are empty so the user can redo the group.
Append the group of entries into the list at end of each loop.
These conditions of break or continue may be changed if preferred.

When the loop ends, if the list is empty then end the script as nothing to do.

Writing the file can be done with a for loop. Use a formatted string so the
group can be written as one group. Formatting allows for further alignment etc.

```
studentInfo = []

while len(studentInfo) < 3:
    firstName = input("Enter your first Name: ")
    if firstName == '':
        break
    lastName = input("Enter your last Name here: ")
    if firstName == '':
        continue
    studentID = input("Enter your id number: ")
    if studentID == '':
        continue

    studentInfo.append([firstName, lastName, studentID])
    print()

if not studentInfo:
    exit()

fileName = "studentInfo.txt"

inFile = open(fileName, 'a')
for firstName, lastName, studentID in studentInfo:
    inFile.write("Name: {} {}\n"
                 "StudentID: {}\n"
                 .format(firstName, lastName, studentID)
                 )
inFile.close()

print("Done! Data is saved in file: " + fileName)
```